# Why is differential geometry called differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, big-picture

Why is differential geometry called differential geometry? Why it is not called differential and integral geometry? Isn't integration and finding areas as important as differentiation? Is it the case that  differential equations are more common and natural in mechanics than integral equations so as a result differential geometry as the language of mechanics is more concerned with differentiation?

Comment: Because 'differential and integral geometry' sounds silly.

Comment: @ChrisDugale there is an area in math called integral geometry. But I don't see why integral geometry is not discussed in general DG books.

Comment: The fundamental theorems in differential geometry are about what the differential of a function reveals about the function's local behaviour. Integral geometry (and geometric measure theory) isn't separate from differential geometry, but it addresses different questions. It is much more about the interplay of submanifolds and measure theory, and often the differentiability assumptions are very weak.

Comment: Why? Because it makes no *difference* either way. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

A few things to keep in mind:

1. A smooth manifold is defined by using the standard differential calculus and not integration.
2. When one speaks about the geometry of a smooth manifold one is fundamentally concerned with questions regarding curvature, which uses the notion of a Riemannian metric and covariant derivatives on the manifold. These are defined by differential and tensor calculus (by constructing the tangent and tensor bundles) and not a priori by doing integration on the manifold.
3. Integration on a manifold is defined for differential forms, which by them selves are defined by differential calculus.

A question: would you call the field "Topology" instead "Topology and continuous maps" just because in topology one often (maybe even most of the time) deals with continuous maps from one space to another? Keep in mind that continuous maps are defined by using the notion of a topology.

Another question: what is a "name"? A "name" should be a term that acts like a basis for the subject in the same sense that a basis for a linear space or a basis for a topology acts: a **short** description that should span rest of the subject in your mind and by practise.

There is no doubt that integration on smooth manifolds is extremely important, but it seems to me like adding "Integral" to the name of the field is unnecessary.

Comment: apart from being coordinate dependent what are other reasons that integration is not as powerful as differential calculus to describe geometrical properties?

Comment: Usually the Riemannian metric of a smooth manifold captures it's geometric properties such as curvatures and angles. One doesn't need to integrate on the manifold to capture these notions.

Answer (score 0):

There are some books covering differential and integral geometry simultaneously. I think the reason is that differential geometry is more common and, like you said, it finds more applications in other branches of science ,mostly theoretical physics, mechanics, etc. On the other hand, if you get into a more serious book on advanced geometry, you can immediately see that integral geometry continues where differential geometry ends.

Comment: No, not really. Integral geometry is sometimes called *geometric probability*. It is concerned with discovering geometric invariants by averaging over slices or projections, or by averaging geometric data of the intersections of two submanifolds as you move one of them around with all possible motions. Crofton's formula (in its various forms) lies at the beginning of the subject of integral geometry.

Comment: This depends on treatment of authors.As you said, sometimes, subject enters another field that int. Geo.  is used densely so names change.  The most I see int. Geo.  is where books on advanced differential geometry finish the subjects related to differentiability and continues with integral transforms.

Comment: True enough. On the analytic side, the Radon transform on homogeneous spaces is an example of what is also called integral geometry in modern days.

Answer (score 0):

Local differential relationship is the basis  leading to determination and evaluation of global (in the large) immersion whenever it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The topics of the *differential* of a map, *differential* forms, exterior *derivative*, covariant *derivative*, Lie *derivative*, might suggest the subject title.